# Probability of traveling from one city to another with probability p of a mudslide blocking roads

Tags: probability

Two roads join Ashville and Benson, and two further roads join Benson to Carlyle. Ashville is directly connected to Carlyle using a railroad. All four roads and the railroad are independently blocked by mudslides with probability p.

(a) If you are at Ashville, what is the probability you can travel to Carlyle, and

(b) if you get there, what is the probability that the railroad is blocked?

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$ Let's number the roads and railroad as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{$1$ and $2$} &:& \text{Ashville to Benson} \\
\text{$3$ and $4$} &:& \text{Benson to Carlyle} \\
5 &:& \text{Ashville to Carlyle.}
\end{eqnarray*}

Let $B_i$, for $i=1,2,3,4,5$, be the event that road/railroad $i$ is blocked. Let $G$ be the event that you can get to Carlyle. Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(G) &=& 1 - P(G^c) \\
&=& 1 - P([(B_1 \cap B_2) \;\cup\; (B_3 \cap B_4)]\; \cap\; B_5) \\
&=& 1 - P((B_1 \cap B_2) \;\cup\; (B_3 \cap B_4))\; P(B_5) \\
&=& 1 - \bigg[P(B_1 \cap B_2) + P(B_3 \cap B_4) - P(B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3 \cap B_4)\bigg] \; P(B_5) \\
&=& 1 - \bigg[P(B_1)P(B_2) + P(B_3)P(B_4) - P(B_1)P(B_2)P(B_3)P(B_4)\bigg] \; P(B_5) \\
&=& 1 - (2p^2 - p^4)p \\
&=& 1 - 2p^3 + p^5.
\end{eqnarray*}

$(b)$

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(B_5 \mid G) &=& 1 - P(B_5^c \mid G) \\
&& \\
&=& 1 - \dfrac{P(G \mid B_5^c)\; P(B_5^c)}{P(G)} \\
&& \\
&=& 1 - \dfrac{1\cdot(1-p)}{1 - 2p^3 + p^5} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{p - 2p^3 + p^5}{1 - 2p^3 + p^5}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}